# Xamarin ODBC Connectivity

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm looking to start a small application for maintenance techs to view production status of lines and whether they are running or currently throwing an error.

*Essentially when a user keys in that the line is experiencing problems it will pass a value to the DB we have. The IOS app should be able to read the data from the table as to take it and then create visual warnings for techs to access view through the app. An example of this would be a small Green/Red Square representing the current status of a line*

Does Xamarin.IOS support this via an ODBC connection? I have done some preliminary searches for accessing the data through a web server but I am not quite how this would be implemented.

Any help would be appreciated - Cheers,

Comment: The better solution would be to write a Web-API layer that handles all the ODBC transactions and then using those API's in your mobile devices

Comment: Doing direct data access from a mobile device is almost always a bad idea.  And ODBC is 30 year old technology.  You really need to figure out how to do this with web services.  There are a huge number of samples available and many different ways to accomplish this, with or without the .NET stack.

Comment: Can you define what a web service would look like - It's a bit difficult for me to picture how this is accomplish. Would you have the DB, display entries to a web page then hook the web page into the app, or is a web-service a non visual way to send information through a "Middleman" of sorts. DB -> Webservice -> App -> User - Then the view is generated in Xamarin with the PHP passed into the application?

Comment: @Adrian, About using webservice to get data, you can take a look:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/consuming/rest

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you can write a separate backend server application to deal with DB. Expose that server through the Restful Web API and then access that Web API from the Mobile app. If you are planning to use an in-app local database, then you can write DB service with SQLite. Refer below link

https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net